# How do I specify both an interface and its type parameters when requesting & referencing a service in OSGi DS?

Tags: java, generics, osgi

I have an interface like:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    void doSomethingWith(T t);
}
```

And some implementations like:

```
class Bar implements Foo<String> {
    void doSomethingWith(String s) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Baz implements Foo<Double> {
    void doSomethingWith(Double d) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have an OSGi service that needs an instance of a Foo<String> (and another service that needs a Foo<Double>, etc.).

Is there a way to expose & thus inject the implementations using Declarative Services? I can only figure out how to expose Bar & Baz as Foo & not as Foo<String> and Foo<Double>, respectively.

Comment: < and > are lost due to formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, there is no such thing as `Foo<String>` at runtime due to the type [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The type information is lost.

Instead, you can expose `Bar` as raw `Foo` with service property `typeArg=java.lang.String` and use filter when injecting it to the consumer.

Other way is to introduce interfaces `FooString extends Foo<String> { }`, `FooDouble extends Foo<Double> { }` and use them instead of `Foo`.

Comment: That is true, but the type parameterizations of Bar & Baz are available via java.lang.reflect.

Comment: I have been using the FooString & FooDouble interface ideas, but I don't like that they're just marker interfaces.

Comment: I ended up using both of these techniques: adding a `type=A` service property for dynamic lookup as well as adding marker interfaces for DS injection when it is statically known what a bundle requires.

Answer (score 0):

In the type Foo, T is erased to object. So the method on the interface is

```
void doSomethingWith(Object t)
```

When you define Bar as implements Foo<String>, you end up with two methods including the compiler generated synthetic bridge method which takes the type Object.

```
void doSomethingWith(Object t) {
    doSomethingWith((String)t);
}
```

But as far as OSGi services are concerned, the type of a service registered under the name Foo is just Foo and any class that implements it must have a doSomethingWith(Object t) method. There is no way (other than you defining and using some service properties) for the framework or Declarative Service to understand the service implementation (e.g. Bar) has defined T to be String.

Comment: The framework or Declarative Service implementation could use java.lang.reflect to determine what the service implementation has defined T to be.

Comment: It's not always possible to do that via reflection. For example, if you have Baz<T> implements Foo<T> { }; Foo<T> foo = new Baz<Long>();, there is no way to find out what T is at runtime, if I'm not mistaken. Even if that is possible it could be not that simple. There could be a whole hierarchy to trace to find out the actual parameter, like: Bar<S, T> implements Foo<T>; Baz<S> extends Bar<S, Long>, etc.

Comment: That is true, but I cannot conceive of how the type parameters would be undiscoverable via reflection within the DS context.

Comment: DS cannot determine the type for T by inspection of the ServiceReference. DS could use the client bundle's class loader to see that type Foo, the declared type of the service, has a formal type T, but how would DS determine what value of T the client bundle expects? DS could get each Foo service object (as the expense of breaking laziness) to inspect for the actual type of T but without knowing how to determine the type of T desired by the client, that is not very useful.